# Is it possible to get data from Cucumber scenario, parse it using a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, parsing, cucumber, bdd, scenarios

I am trying figure out how to parse a feature file, and get the name and description  of every scenario in the feature file to put into a CSV file. For example if I had a cucumber scenario like so

```
Feature: Feature Info

Scenario: Name 1
Description 1
    Rest of the cucumber script

Scenario: Name 2
Description 2
    Rest of the cucumber script
```

I would be able to take out the Name data and Description, so I could that into a cell in CSV. The cells would end up something like:

```
First Column - Scenario Name Header: Name 1, Name 2
Second Column - Scenario Description Header: Description 1, Description 2
```

I don't have any code yet, since I am not sure where to start really. Any help would be great.

Comment: Ruby has a [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) class that you can use to access the feature files and a [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class that you could write to.

Comment: @orde I am already utilizing that to get other file data into a CSV file. I guess what I am asking is if I can get Strings from a feature file. Essentially can it be read like just like a text file, or is there anything else I need to do.

Comment: Once you've opened a feature file, you can use the [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html) class to access data in the file (e.g. `IO::read`).  From there, you'll have to manipulate the data to make it into whatever format you want in the `CSV`.  Give it a shot and post some code when you run into trouble.  You'll get a more meaningful response that way.

Comment: Given the origin of Cucumber, this question just tickles me pink. Thank you. http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2007/10/21/story-runner-in-plain-english/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a cucumber feature file is just a text file.  You can open it and read it line by line in Ruby as with any other ASCII/UTF8 character file.  You can use the Ruby match instruction to select and classify lines and extract the desired information. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html

Since you are building a unit record out of multiple lines you will need to hold state until you are finished processing each group.

```
 File.open( feature_file ).each do |line|
   # do matching here
   # build unit record
   # pass to output
   # rinse and repeat
 end
```